# Set specific image to Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I set multiple image sources for a div using javascript function. I want that when user clicks to the button then only a specific image set to that div.

```js
function changeColor1() {
  document.getElementById("myDIV").style = "background-image:url(coloredshirtsimages/coloredwithoutsleeve/red_withoutsleeve.png)"
  document.getElementById("myDIV").style = "background-image:url(coloredshirtsimages/coloredhalfsleeveroundneck/red_halfsleeve.png)"
  document.getElementById("myDIV").style = "background-image:url(coloredshirtsimages/coloredfullhalf/red_fullhalfsleeve.png)"
  document.getElementById("myDIV").style = "background-image:url(coloredshirtsimages/coloredfullsleeve/red_fullsleeve.png)"
  document.getElementById("myDIV").style = "background-image:url(coloredshirtsimages/coloredfullsleevev-neck/red_fullsleevevneck.png)"
  document.getElementById("myDIV").style = "background-image:url(coloredshirtsimages/coloredshirtsimages/coloredvneck/red_vneck.png)"
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV"></div>
<button style="background-color:red;outline:none" class="colors" onclick="changeColor1()"></button>
```

```
#myDIV {
    width: 550px;
    height: 650px;
    background-image: url(coloredshirtsimages/coloredhalfsleeveroundneck/white_halfsleeve.png);
    border: 2px solid black;
    color: orange;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 200px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I changed the image using css and javascript now the image belongs to particular category for example(white_vneck)is goes to div but problem is that only one image was gone to div. I want that other image (red_vneck.png) goes to div when i clicked the button in place of white_vneck.
Please feel free to ask a question if you have any confusion

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems like you forgot to add your HTML code to the question. Can you add it please?

Comment: How do you want to determine the specific image? If the button is clicked clicked, what's supposed to happen? which one of the images and where do you want to show up? Is it random?

Comment: @Joojoo did you try my answer?

Comment: @dev8080 thanks it worked but i don't want to write a particular image url. I want that the image came in div randomly when a particular condition is fulfilled

Comment: @Joojoo so is the logic for showing image random or particular?

Comment: @dev8080 Randomly selects a particular image

Comment: @Joojoo See my edit. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @dev8080 Thanku so much for your great help. It worked.

Comment: @Joojoo If it helped, do mark it as the answer :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a parameter to your function to help it understand which image you wish to display:

```
    onclick="changeColor1('abc.png')"


    function changeColor1(pic) {
      document.getElementById("myDIV").style = "background-image:url(" + pic + ")";
    }
```

According your code snippet:

```js
function changeColor1(pngName) {
  document.getElementById("myDIV").style = "background-image:url("+pngName+")";
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV"></div>
<button style="background-color:red;outline:none" class="colors" onclick="changeColor1('coloredshirtsimages/coloredwithoutsleeve/red_withoutsleeve.png')"></button>
```

For selecting random image:

```
    onclick="changeColor1()"

    var pics =[
                    'coloredwithoutsleeve/red_withoutsleeve.png' , 
                    'coloredhalfsleeveroundneck/red_halfsleeve.png', 
                    'coloredfullhalf/red_fullhalfsleeve.png',
                    'coloredfullsleeve/red_fullsleeve.png',
                    'coloredfullsleevev-neck/red_fullsleevevneck.png',
                    'coloredshirtsimages/coloredvneck/red_vneck.png'
            ];
    function changeColor1() {
        //random selection of pic
        var picIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * pics.length);
        document.getElementById("myDIV").style = "background-image:url(coloredshirtsimages/" + pics[picIndex] + ")";
    }
```

Comment: @surajrawat It works fine. I have tried it. Was that the reason for the downvote?

Comment: @surajrawat Well I haven't downvoted...your solution is different by mine by taht detail..and it works..can be easily verified dear friend by running it. The code snippet itself is for that purpose. Why ask in a code forum why something runs?

Comment: @surajrawat How would it run in the code snippet then? Runs fine for me. "Cannot set property 'style' of null" is not because the style-setting is wrong, it is because the element cannot be found. A dozen ways exist to set the colour...I could list them all here but the point of the answer was to structure function call n all. When you answer a question, you need to be open to other suggestions. This is too minor an issue. Let the OP decide finally.